# Handling long actions in rclpy (with cancellation)

Tags: ros, ros2, action, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Fibonacci action demo](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/humble/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_py/action_tutorials_py/fibonacci_action_server.py) is nice, but it doesn't support cancellation.

I added a custom `cancel_callback`, called it from `ros2 action send_goal`, and tried to cancel by hitting ctrl-C, but it doesn't seem to work. I suspect that's because `execute_callback` is blocking.

What is a preferred pattern for handling long-running actions in rclpy with cancellation? Any examples / demos / tutorials?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409537/handling-long-actions-in-rclpy-(with-cancellation)/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2022-11-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whoops, I looked at the [rclpy demos](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/humble/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_py),
but forgot about the [rclpy examples](https://github.com/ros2/examples/tree/master/rclpy/actions).

There are several server examples showing how to build long-running action servers that handle cancellation. They work well w/ the client examples, as well as `ros2 action send_goal`.

In looking at the server code, I see a few patterns:

- execute_callback contains a call to time.sleep() to simulate a long-running action
- execute_callback blocks until the goal has been reached, or a cancellation request has been received
- the trick is to use a MultiThreadedExecutor and a ReentrantCallbackGroup: these allow the server to receive and process cancellation requests while the goal is executing
- in some cases the execute_callback is marked async, but this doesn't matter, since it never yields (never awaits)

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2022-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0